# Greater than / less than between the elements of two arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok so I have two integer arraylist  and I want to compare each element that matches  the index of the other arraylist. I then want to loop through both arraylist and if one element is greater than the other I want to store that element in one of two new list.  if the elements are the same than return nothing or null.

The Arraylist

```
arr1 ={3,4,0};   arr2={7,2,1};
```

Result I want

```
arr1greater {4};  arr2greater {7,1};
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both array1 and array2 are having same length:

```
for(int i=0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    int a1 = array1.get(i);
    int a2 = array2.get(i);
    if(a1 > a2) {
        array1Greater.add(a1);
    } else if(a2 > a1) {
        array2Greater.add(a2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anil I seriously couldn't find it. It looks simple now that it was explain to me.

Comment: If the solution is satisfactory please mark it as a solution